# После получения сайта через file_get_contents на нем не работает javascript

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Пытаюсь получить эту страницу при помощи file_get_contents: https://livetour.roomee.pro/object/5bab3d3443367a013888204a. Вот такой код:

```html
$page = file_get_contents('https://livetour.roomee.pro/object/'.$_GET['id']);
$pagewithlinks = str_replace ('/static','https://livetour.roomee.pro/static',$page);
echo ($pagewithlinks);
```

Php получает весь html, но панорама почему-то не показывается. В консоли бразуера вижу, что медиа содержимое не подгружается. Подскажите, в чем может быть дело?

Comment: для подобных целей `iframe` существует.

Comment: К сожалению, здесь iframe не подходит.

Comment: Что означает "не подгружается" ? консоль браузера, а особенно раздел "Network" дает гораздо больше полезной информации. Наиболее вероятно, что ссылки на сайте все относительные, без указания домена, а следовательно при получении контента к ним добавляется ваш домен, а не домен того сайта и вы это не исправите не поменяв текст html (ну или не подняв у себя полноценный прокси, вместо php скрипта)

Comment: Вторая строчка в php скрипте как раз подменяет относительные линки на абсолютные. Файлы по ним открываются. Вкладка network как раз и не показывает, чтобы что-то подгружалось. На оригинальной странице после того, как загрузятся все ресурсы с livetour.roomee.pro, начинает загружаться медиасодержимое с storage.roomee.pro. При этом в div'е на главной появляется html содержимое, в которое потом, собственно, медиа и отображается. А у меня ничего этого не происходит. Из этого и делаю вывод, что javascript не работает.